# How to replace the "Kubernetes fake certificate" with a wildcard certificate (on bare metal private cloud) Nginx Ingress and cert manager

Tags: certificate, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, bare-metal-server

We have setup a Kubernetes cluster on our bare metal server.

We deploy our application where each namespace is an application for the end customer. ie customer1.mydomain.com -> namespace: cust1

We keep on getting the Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate.

We have purchased our own wildcard certificates *.mydomain.com

```
#kubectl create secret tls OUR-SECRET --key /path/private.key --cert /path/chain.crt -n ingress-nginx
#kubectl create secret tls OUR-SECRET --key /path/private.key --cert /path/chain.crt -n kube-system
```

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1  
kind: Certificate  
metadata:  
  name: ourcloud
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:  
  secretName: oursecret
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  commonName: '*.mydomain.com'
  acme:
    config:
    - dns01:
        provider: cf-dns-prod
      domains:
      - '*.mydomain.com'

kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
certificate.certmanager.k8s.io/ourcloud created
```

https://cust1.mydomain.com connects with Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate

Comment: Have you tried following this [guide](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/tutorials/acme/quick-start/index.html)?

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem. I had the wrong filename in my yaml for the certificate files.  Its allways good to look at the ingress logs

```
kubectl logs nginx-ingress-controller-689498bc7c-tf5 -n ingress-nginx   



kubectl get -o yaml  ingress --all-namespaces
```

Try to recreate the secrete from files and see if it works.

```
kubectl delete -n cust4 SECRETNAME

kubectl -n cust4 create secret tls SECRETENAME --key key.key --cert cert.crt
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Helm` and `cert manager`, make sure each ingress resource has a different `certificate name`, these values are usually set from the values file in a helm chart.

`tls
  - secretName: <give certificate name>
    hosts: example.com`

You can check the certificates available using to avoid name collision if you have successfully deployed your ingress resources:

`kubectl get certificates`

Comment: `> kubectl get certificates` -> 
`error: the server doesn't have a resource type "certificates"`

Comment: It means no certificates have been created yet on the server, have you deployed ingress resources yet?  `kubectl get ingress` to check

Comment: The certificate resources will be automatically created when you deploy your ingress resources.

Comment: The `Certificate` resource does not come from NGINX Ingress. Instead, that resource type is installed on your cluster when you install the `cert-manager` service.